# Expand/Collapse All the groups in extjs Grid with the keyboard navigation

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6

How to expand/collapse all the groups in grouping extjs grid with the keyboard. And how to get focus on the groups with the keyboard and expand each group with the tab change or something like that. Please let me know any ideas on that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ext.dom.Element keypress](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-keypress) event for top level DOM element representing grid (use [Ext.grid.Panel.getEl()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getEl)) and [Ext.grid.feature.Grouping](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping) methods to work with grouping feature.

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rj9) for example. Press 'C' key to collapse all groups and 'T' key to toggle groups.

*I wrote this code for ExtJS4, but it seems to work with ExtJS6.*